# Netbeans run application and jar file are scaled up

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am using Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4 with JDK 16.
I have jar apps, and when running those projects in NetBeans they are scaled up incorrectly. They only show properly when I set my windows scale to 100%. But that is too small, and I only use it at 125%.

This shows what it is supposed to look like:

[image: java application before scaling issues]

And this shows what it looks like right now, with scaling issues:

[image: java application with scaling issues]

The icons are all jagged, and images don't show up correctly. I have the same issue with all my other jar executable files.

How do I correct this scaling issue?

I tried changing the compatibility mode and also editing the config file for netbeans, but nothing is working.

Comment: Why you think this is a NetBeans issue? What kind of UI Framework you use? Actually I don't see that difference in the pictures above. So your problem is quite unclear.

Comment: ok, well a while back the scaling issues only occurred in the jar files that are created when building a project, and when using run, in NetBeans, it was scaled properly. but now even when running it in NetBeans, it is scaled incorrectly. I am using the default JFrame GUI editor in NetBeans. And the issue is not quite visible in the picture above because it is mainly text, but inside the application, there are a bunch of icons I have used which are now too big and have jagged edges.